# What command are my volume keys running?

Tags: sound, xfce

In Unity I use my ThinkPad hot keys to change the volume. I need to know the command that these keys run so that I can bind it in my window manager.

I have tried using amixer but could not change the volume through command line

> **amixer set Master 10%- amixer:** Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
>
> **amixer scontrols:** Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
>
> **amixer set 'IEC958' 50%- amixer:** Invalid command!

So obviously this is not what Unity is running. I have tried changing the default sound card as well but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so basically they're not simple keybinding->command process, MediaKeys give you scancode which is interpreted by X.
Some reading for you https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys

Comment: I guess this must be right because nothing I've tried affects the volume.

Answer (score 1):

The following command:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 50%
```

will set the volume at 50%. To increase the volume with 10% you can use:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- +10%
```

To decrease the volume with 10% you can use:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 0 -- -10%
```